# Pear not installing correctly

Tags: php, pear

Trying to install Pear on Windows Server 2012 R2. Current version of PHP is 5.3.28.

I am using the `go-pear.phar` file to install it by running `php go-pear.phar`. This works fine until the actual installing begins. 
[image]

After the 5 installing lines, the script just exits without having installed any of the actual files. It creates the `pear.ini` file and the folders specified in the configuration, but none of the actual Pear files are installed. No error message is given. From looking at tutorials online, I know that it is supposed to install the files and alter the `php.ini` file, but this is not happening in my case.

Comment: Have you tried installing using homebrew?

Comment: @ElroyJetson does homebrew work on windows?

Comment: @DerekPollard yes https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/ I'm not really a windows user, so I'm not sure if it's applicable to OP, but I stopped bothering to install stuff without package management software a long time ago.